# How do I solve this pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

error: cannot find symbol
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

This is the error am getting. Am new in using PDFBox and now am trying to write into a pdf file and I must specify the font but the font is bringing the error. I am compiling in terminal for those guys using IDE's am not. e.g (java -cp commons-logging-1.2.jar:fontbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar:pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar:pdfbox-tools-3.0.0-alpha2.jar:preflight-3.0.0-alpha2.jar:xmpbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar doc1.java)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're new then use 2.0.25 instead of an alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check PDFBox 3.0 Migration Guide but as @tilman-hausherr said if you are newly started using PDFBox use 2.0.25 otherwise you will have other problems because PDFBox3, is not a stable version yet.
If you are consistent to use this version, please provide more cues and also add your code.

Static instances for Standard 14 fonts removed
The static instances of PDType1Font for the standard 14 fonts were removed as the underlying COSDictionary isn't supposed to be immutable which led to several issues.

A new constructor for PDType1Font was introduced to create a standard 14 font. The new Enum Standard14Fonts.FontName is the one and only parameter and defines the name of the standard 14 font for which the instance of PDType1Font is created for. That instance isn't a singleton anymore and has to be recreated if necessary or cached by the user if suitable.

https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html