# How to set font ON org.apache.pdfbox WHILE Migrating from 3.0.0-RC1 to 3.0.0

Tags: fonts, migration, pdfbox

I have a simple working 3.0.0.RC1 example [code](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.file.pdf/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/api/file/pdf/server/pdfbox/TS_FilePdfBoxUtils.java) as below:

```
try (var document = new PDDocument();) {
  var page = new PDPage();
  document.addPage(page);
  try (var contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);) {
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
    contentStream.showText("Hello World");
    contentStream.endText();
  }
  document.save(path.toFile());
```

When i change the version from 3.0.0.RC1 to 3.0.0 current code below is not working:

```
    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
```

I tried below code, but it gives error: "PDFont is abtract; cannot be instantiated:"

```
    contentStream.setFont(new PDFont(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA_BOLD), 12);
```

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html#static-instances-for-standard-14-fonts-removed

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr I have read it and missed it. Because, while using an ide, she asked me to supply (abstract class) PDFont, not super class (PDType1Font ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to answer [How do I solve this pdfbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509625/how-do-i-solve-this-pdfbox)

I tried this code, and it compiles.

```
contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA_BOLD), 12);
```